# Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\login.php on line 21 null

Tags: php

I have the below warning message which I am trying to resolve:

> Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\login.php on line 21 null

```php
<?php
    require "init.php";

    $email=$_POST["email"];
    $password=$_POST["password"];

    $sql="SELECT name,email FROM request WHERE email LIKE'".$email."' AND 
    password LIKE '".$password."';";

    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
   // $response=array();

   if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
      {

        $row= mysqli_fetch_row($result);
        $name=$row[0];
        $email=$row[1];
        $code="login success";
        array_push($response,array("code"=>$code));
        echo json_encode($response);
      }
      else
      {
       $code="reg_failed";
       $message="Please Enter right email or password ";
       array_push($response,array("code"=>$code,"message"=>$message));
       echo json_encode($response);

      }

   mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Do you store passwords in plain text?

Comment: That's because you've commented this line: `$response=array();`

Comment: you have commented `$response=array();`. Uncomment it. As variable should be initialized to push values.

Comment: You should **hash your password** and use **prepared statements for SQL** - otherwise your code is very insecure!

Answer (score -1):

**array_push** should be used with and **array** variable's then **$response** must be declared as an **array**

Uncomment your `$response=array();`

To secure your application

- Use PDO instead of MySQLi
- Hash your password before the insertion by using **md5()** or **sha1()** or **hash()** or **bcrypt** ... (I recommand bcrypt)